# Can anyone tell me why on the lubuntu website there are 2 different sizes of the same installer?

Tags: installation, lubuntu

I decided to download Lubuntu 12.10 and if I click on the regular download...I get a 699 Mb file. If I opt for the torrent, I get a 733 Mb file. Is this normal? Or the 733-Mb file comes with some updates?

In fact.....no matter where you download it from, it is a 733-Mb file, but for some reason....while it is being downloaded, it shows that a 699-Mb file is being downloaded. Weird.

Comment: whatever you do, check the m5dsum against the original spec.

Comment: I can do the checksum the iso, but that's it. I dont find info on how to checksum Lubuntu. Anyway....I am writing the iso to a disc and it fails the checksum so something is not okay here.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [Why is Ubuntu reporting a slightly different size for my Virtualbox disk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150217/why-is-ubuntu-reporting-a-slightly-different-size-for-my-virtualbox-disk)

Answer (score 5):

It's [base-2 arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Deviation_between_powers_of_1024_and_powers_of_1000):

> 699MB * 1024 bytes * 1024 kilo-bytes = 733 x 10^6

Network speeds and unfortunately storage from HDD manufacturers is reported in base-10.  Storage in software is reported in base-2, Windows and other vendors have started to use base-10 measurements to aid confusion.