# 100MB of RAM not detected on 64-bit 12.10 (NVIDIA cards)

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, ram

My desktop's wubi install does not properly detect my NVIDIA graphics card and reports 3.9GB of RAM out of 4GB. On my netbook, which has an NVIDIA ION and 2GB RAM, Sysinfo reports 1.9GB RAM but shows my video card information properly.

It never happened to me with old versions. Do you have any ideas regarding these issues?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`?

Comment: 2041288KB

Dividing by 1024 twice gives 1.946723934GB

Comment: If you solved your problem post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might have something to do with Gibibytes vs Gigabytes as the default unit being used.

See the answer to [Why is Ubuntu reporting a slightly different size for my Virtualbox disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150217/why-is-ubuntu-reporting-a-slightly-different-size-for-my-virtualbox-disk)

Comment: That is not a possibility as Windows 7 reports the correct amount of RAM and what you pointed out only applies to hard drive space.